# How to store a lot of textures?

Tags: javascript, three.js

i have some project which uses a lot of sprites, and now i'm storing them in many pngs file. I understand that i do it wrong, so what is the proper way to store them. May be convert in some format to keep them in few files? I was thinking about texture atlas, but my sprites sizes starts from 256x256 and texture atlas will be too big

Comment: Why do you think this is the wrong way? What have you tried to resolve the issues you're seeing?

Comment: A texture atlas seems like the right idea. If your textures are too big for that, and you have a lot of them, I think you may be out of luck. You could pack them all into a binary file to reduce requests on load, but it won't help runtime performance at all.